# Pandas .groupby and .mean() based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following large dataset recording the result of a math competition among students in descending order of date: So for example, student 1 comes third in Race 1 while student 3 won Race 2, etc.

```
Race_ID   Date           Student_ID      Rank    Studying_hours
1         1/1/2023       1               3       2
1         1/1/2023       2               2       5
1         1/1/2023       3               1       7
1         1/1/2023       4               4       1
2         11/9/2022      1               2       4
2         11/9/2022      2               3       2
2         11/9/2022      3               1       8
3         17/4/2022      5               4       3
3         17/4/2022      2               1       7
3         17/4/2022      3               2       2
3         17/4/2022      4               3       3
4         1/3/2022       1               3       7
4         1/3/2022       2               2       2 
5         1/1/2021       1               2       2
5         1/1/2021       2               3       3
5         1/1/2021       3               1       6
```

and I want to generate a new column called "winning_past_studying_hours" which is the average studying hours of his past competitions and where he ended up with Rank 1 or 2.

So for example, for student 1:

```
Race_ID Date    Student_ID  Rank    Studying_hours
1   1/1/2023    1           3       2
2   11/9/2022   1           2       4
4   1/3/2022    1           3       7
5   1/1/2021    1           2       2
```

the column looks like

```
Race_ID Date    Student_ID  Rank    Studying_hours    winning_past_studying_hours
1   1/1/2023    1           3       2                 (4+2)/2 = 3
2   11/9/2022   1           2       4                 2/1 = 2
4   1/3/2022    1           3       7                 2/1= 2
5   1/1/2021    1           2       2                 NaN
```

Similarly, for student 2:

```
Race_ID Date    Student_ID  Rank    Studying_hours
1   1/1/2023    2           2       5
2   11/9/2022   2           3       2
3   17/4/2022   2           1       7
4   1/3/2022    2           2       2
5   1/1/2021    2           3       3
```

The column looks like

```
Race_ID Date    Student_ID  Rank    Studying_hours    winning_past_studying_hours
1   1/1/2023    2           2       5                 (7+2)/2=4.5
2   11/9/2022   2           3       2                 (7+2)/2=4.5
3   17/4/2022   2           1       7                 2/1=2
4   1/3/2022    2           2       2                 NaN
5   1/1/2021    2           3       3                 NaN
```

I know the basic `groupby` and `mean` function but I do not know how to include the condition `Rank.isin([1,2])` in the `groupby` function. Thank you so much.

EDIT: Desired output:

```
Race_ID   Date           Student_ID      Rank    Studying_hours  winning_past_studying_hours
1         1/1/2023       1               3       2               3
1         1/1/2023       2               2       5               4.5
1         1/1/2023       3               1       7               5.333
1         1/1/2023       4               4       1               NaN
2         11/9/2022      1               2       4               2
2         11/9/2022      2               3       2               4.5
2         11/9/2022      3               1       8               4
3         17/4/2022      5               4       3               NaN
3         17/4/2022      2               1       7               2
3         17/4/2022      3               2       2               6
3         17/4/2022      4               3       3               NaN
4         1/3/2022       1               3       7               2
4         1/3/2022       2               2       2               NaN
5         1/1/2021       1               2       2               NaN
5         1/1/2021       2               3       3               NaN
5         1/1/2021       3               1       6               NaN
```

Comment: add the desired output in full

Comment: @SebastianWozny Hi I just edited and added the desired output in full, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We replace the studying hours for every competition a student didn't "win" with `np.NaN` which has no impact on the calculation of the mean.

Use a window function [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/window.html#window-expanding) with a large number to get an expanding window over the entries and compute the past running mean by specifying `closed='left'` which discards the most recent entry.

Then we join back.

```
large_number=100000

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Studying_hours']=((df.Rank<3)*df.Studying_hours).replace({0:np.NaN}) # This is more performant than an apply with a lambda
winning=df.sort_values('Date').groupby('Student_ID')['Studying_hours'].rolling(large_number,closed='left',min_periods=1).mean()
df['past_winning_hours_mean']=winning.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

Test:

```
>>> df.sort_values(['Date', 'Student_ID'])
```

Output:

```
Race_ID Date    Student_ID  Rank    Studying_hours  past_winning_hours_mean
13  5   2021-01-01  1   2   2.0 NaN
14  5   2021-01-01  2   3   NaN NaN
15  5   2021-01-01  3   1   6.0 NaN
11  4   2022-01-03  1   3   NaN 2.000000
12  4   2022-01-03  2   2   2.0 NaN
8   3   2022-04-17  2   1   7.0 2.000000
9   3   2022-04-17  3   2   2.0 6.000000
10  3   2022-04-17  4   3   NaN NaN
7   3   2022-04-17  5   4   NaN NaN
4   2   2022-11-09  1   2   4.0 2.000000
5   2   2022-11-09  2   3   NaN 4.500000
6   2   2022-11-09  3   1   8.0 4.000000
0   1   2023-01-01  1   3   NaN 3.000000
1   1   2023-01-01  2   2   5.0 4.500000
2   1   2023-01-01  3   1   7.0 5.333333
3   1   2023-01-01  4   4   NaN NaN
```

I profiled this code on a dataset with 30000 rows:

```
6.07 ms ± 45.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I think the code didn't take into the account that we are taking average of past studying hours, thank you for your help.

Comment: now it's correct

Comment: thank you so much! the code works. But since my original dataset is huge, it takes a long time to run (I think it's the if else part that's computationally heavy), is there any more computationally efficient way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: I found the real answer. no more crutch `.apply` which is slow.